# How to factorize a Linq request with multiple includes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity

I want to simplify a linq Query that contains multiple includes.

My model is simple: a site is linked to one contract, that is linked to one client. On that client I need to get with a single request the telephones, mails and honorifics (appelRef).

I want a single request because behind the request is translated by entity framework into a SQL Server request.

Here is the linq request:

```
var search =
from IMT.Site s in imtContext.IMTObjects.OfType<IMT.Site>()
.Include(
s => s.LienContratSiteRef
    .Select(l => l.Contrat)
        .Select(c => c.LienContratClientRef
            .Select(l => l.Client)
                .Select(cl => cl.Telephones ) ) )

.Include(s => s.LienContratSiteRef
    .Select(l => l.Contrat)
        .Select(c => c.LienContratClientRef
            .Select(l => l.Client)
                .Select(cl => cl.Mails ) ) )

.Include(s => s.LienContratSiteRef
    .Select(l => l.Contrat)
        .Select(c => c.LienContratClientRef
            .Select(l => l.Client)
                .Select(cl => cl.AppelRef ) ) )

where s.Reference.ToString() == siteId
select s;
```

Yor can notice the block

```
.Include(
s => s.LienContratSiteRef
    .Select(l => l.Contrat)
        .Select(c => c.LienContratClientRef
            .Select(l => l.Client)
```

..is repeated three time. Is ther a way to factorize that code block ?

Update: there are intermedray objects LienContratSiteRef and LienContratClientRef and relationships are 0 - *, so that LienContratSiteRef.Contrat and LienContratClientRef.Client are collections.

I also tried:

```
.Include(
s => s.LienContratSiteRef
    .Select(l => l.Contrat)
        .Select(c => c.LienContratClientRef
            .Select(l => l.Client)
                .Select(cl => new { Tels = cl.Telephones, Mail = cl.Mails, Appel = cl.AppelRef} ) ) )
```

but It results with a runtime error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type.

Comment: You can do that, but it will require to construct Include expression manually, which might result in quite some code (though this code might be reused later for similar cases I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

**String-based Chaining**

The [`Include()` method supports a dot-delimited string parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used to pull an complete graph of objects down as opposed to making multiple chained select calls:

```
.Include("LienContratSiteRif.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client")
```

From there, if you wanted to include multiple additional properties, I believe that you could have another include for those sub properties:

```
.Include("LienContratSiteRif.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client, Client.Telephones, ...")
```

**Lambda-based Chaining**

You should be able to accomplish something similar by chaining your lambda-based includes into a single `Include()` call as well using:

`.Include(c => LienContratSiteRif.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client)`

Comment: It does work with that syntax:
.Include("LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client.Telephones")                      .Include("LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client.Mails")                        .Include("LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client.AppelRef") the downside is no compile time error when the model changes. The second form Client.Mails, Client.AppelRef does not work. I Cannot use the last form because Contrat does not have a navigation property to LienContratSiteRef and LienContratClientRef.

Answer (score 0):

The `s => ...` inside the include could be refactored into a delegate, then just `.Include` that delegate multiple times.

It looks like the signature would be `Func<Site, IEnumerable<Client>>`?

E.g.

```
static IEnumerable<Client> Foo(Site site) => site.LienContratSiteRef
    .Select(l => l.Contrat)
        .Select(c => c.LienContratClientRef
            .Select(l => l.Client)
```

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like you're trying to make an entity framework projection!**

A project allows you to select only the properties that you want to return. (just like a SQL Select)

To use a projection, your code should roughly look like this:

```
var search = imtContext.IMTObjects.OfType<IMT.Site>()
.Where(s => s.Reference.ToString() == siteId)
.Select(s => new {
     Telephones = s.LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.Select(c =>  c.LienContratClientRef.Client.Select(cli => cli.Telephones), 
     Mails = s.LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.Select(c =>  c.LienContratClientRef.Client.Select(cli => cli.Mails), 
     AppelRef = s.LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.Select(c =>  c.LienContratClientRef.Client.Select(cli => cli.AppelRef)     
}).ToList();
```

If `Telephones`, `Mails`, `AppelRef`are also collections, then you can do aggregate the collections together like this in memory after the query has been run:

```
var telephones = search.SelectMany(x => x.Telephones).ToList();
var mails = search.SelectMany(x => x.Mails).ToList();
var appelRefs = search.SelectMany(x => x.AppelRef).ToList();
```

Comment: I cannot used the syntax s.LienContratSiteRef.Contrat.LienContratClientRef.Client.Telephones because LienContratSiteRef.Contrat and LienContratClientRef.Client are collections (I just updated the question to add the precision).